# Is there a possibility to automate the process of deleting user in Wordpress Admin using Selenium?

Tags: wordpress, selenium, testing

I'm trying to make an automated test which consists of registering a new user and deleting it, so this test could be run multiple times. On wp-admin/users.php there is a table, where each user is formatted as "tr". Can I get user id (specifically it's number), if I have user's email?

Right now I'm trying to make a list of Web Elements, convert it to string (getAttribute("outerHTML") and reduce its size to 1 element, that contains email. But I don't know how to deconstruct the string, so I can get the needed id number.

```html
List<WebElement> trTags = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
List<String> users = trTags.stream().filter(item -> item.isDisplayed()).map(item->item.getAttribute("outerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList());
users.removeIf(elem -> !elem.contains("test@test.com"));
users.stream().forEach(elem -> System.out.println(elem));
```

This is what the result looks like

```html
<tr id="user-20">
<th scope="row" class="check-column">
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="user_20">Select *username*</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="users[]" id="user_20" class="subscriber" value="20">
</th>
<td class="username column-username has-row-actions column-primary" data-colname="Username">
<img alt="" src="*imageurl" class="avatar avatar-32 " height="32" width="32" style="height:32px;width:32px">
 <strong><a href="edituserurlinwpadmin">*username*</a></strong><br><div class="row-actions">
 <span class="edit"><a href="*edituserurlinwpadmin*">Edit</a> | </span><span class="delete">
 <a class="submitdelete" href="users.php?action=delete&amp;user=20&amp;_wpnonce=091d3cc8bb">Delete</a> | </span><span class="view">
 <a href="viewuserinwpadmin" aria-label="View posts by *user's name*">View</a> </span></div>
 <button type="button" class="toggle-row"><span class="screen-reader-text">Show more details</span> </button> </td>
 <td class="name column-name" data-colname="Name">*user's firstname & lastname*</td>
 <td class="email column-email" data-colname="Email"><a href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</a></td>
 <td class="role column-role" data-colname="Role">Subscriber</td><td class="posts column-posts num" data-colname="Posts">0</td>
 <td class="heateor_ss_delete_profile_data column-heateor_ss_delete_profile_data" data-colname="Delete Social Profile">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Click to delete social profile data" alt="Click to delete social profile data" onclick="javascript:heateorSsDeleteSocialProfile(this, 20)">Delete</a></td></tr>
```

Comment: When you say `user id ` , does that mean id which appear on the check box ?

Comment: @cruisepandey, yeah, I think it will be the most convenient value to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly write xpath that will match with your **email id** (that you already have) and can get the **id**.

**xpath** :

```
//a[text()='test@test.com']/preceding-sibling::input
```

If you want to make it more dynamic, you could something like :

```
//a[text()='"+emailId+"']/preceding-sibling::input
```

Where **emailId** will be a String that will hold your desire email id.

Now, you can write simple Java code like this :

```
String userId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='test@test.com']/preceding-sibling::input")]/preceding-sibling::input")).getAttribute("id");
System.out.println(userId);
```

You can just change the xpath for dynamic use.

Hope this will help.

**Update :**

As `th` is `preceding-sibling` of `anchor tag`, you have got the right result.

```
//a[text()='test@test.com']/preceding-sibling::th/input
```

Comment: Strange, I get an error "unable to locate element" if I use
"//a[text()='test@test.com']/preceding-sibling::input"
However, if I use 
"//a[contains(.,'"+emailAddressString+"')]/preceding::th/input"
and search for desired email beforehand, I get the needed "20" value

Comment: might be there are trailing spaces, it'd be safe to use :`//a[contains(text(),'test@test.com')]/preceding-sibling::input` , if this answer was helpful please check the check box which is just besides my answer , so this ticket will be closed.

Comment: I have a feeling that "contains" or "text()" is not the case here, because they both return correct value. When using "/preceding-sibling::input" error "unable to locate element" is returned, using "/preceding::input" returns incorrect value and only if I use "/preceding::th/input" a correct value (20) is returned

Comment: Ok, I might have missed the `th`, preceding-sibling is a type of sibling that is just elder than your current node, and it's true also, you can verify in shard HTML.

Comment: th is `preceding-sibling` that has input as child tag. I have updated the answer for future readers. Though it's working fine for you.

Comment: Although I've achieved what I wanted, but there are still some thing to think about: 1) the use of "preceding-sibling" - when I run a testng selenium test in eclipse with "/preceding-sibling::th/input" I receive and error "unable to locate element", however using "/preceding::th/input" will give me some kind of result; 2) "preceding-sibling" (or "preceding") returns the first found result, and if there are more users in table you will have to use a small workaround - search for user with desired email